# How to fix TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Python?

Tags: python

How can I resolve this problem?

```
def common_elements(tuple1, tuple2):
    set1 = set(tuple1)
    set2 = set(tuple2)
    lst1 = list(set1.intersection(set2))
    return tuple(lst1.sort()) #TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

print(common_elements((1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 53, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 0)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> list.sort() will sort the list in-place, but the return value is None.
>
> sorted(list) will return a new list object that is sorted.

The correct code should thus be:

```py
def common_elements(tuple1, tuple2):
    set1 = set(tuple1)
    set2 = set(tuple2)
    lst1 = list(set1.intersection(set2))
    return tuple(sorted(lst1))

print(common_elements((1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 53, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` sorts a list in place and returns `None`. You need to call `sort()` and then return the same list in two different statements:

```
lst1.sort()
return tuple(lst1)
```

Comment: I used it: return tuple(sorted(lst1)) and everything works. Thanks man!

Comment: @SetUpSim you could actually do `sorted(set1.intersection(set2))` directly which would produce the list, avoiding the intermediate `lst1`, and then you can wrap `tuple` around all of that.